# Why am I experiencing extreme packet loss?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, packet-loss, packet-injection

Out of nowhere I have begun seeing large amounts of packet loss. I  made sure I am up to date with any updates including drivers and everything says it's up to date. I use an ethernet cord with a private network and it still seems to be terrible. On the router a red flashing light flickers to the number where the ethernet cord is plugged in and I don't know why that is. So I purchased a brand new ethernet cord and it is now a white light like the rest but on the back of my PC where I plug the ethernet cord in there is a red flashing light and a green light. Any fixes?
[image: the images show ping tests]
[image: the images show ping tests]

Comment: "on the router a red flashing light flickers to the number where the ethernet cord is plugged in and I yet to know why that as so I purchased a brand new"

I suggest you return it as it appears that is it not working correctly.  Start with a straight replacement unit.

Answer (score 1):

Your solid green light on the back is the link light, and is saying you have a connection. The blinking amber light is your activity light, saying you have activity, and a link speed of 1 Gbps.

Your output does not indicate extreme packet loss like you're saying. It's only a 2% packet loss. You're also pining Google, in which the traffic goes out to your ISP and the Internet. At that point it's out of your control. During busy times, I can do the same thing, and see a variation in packet loss when simply trying to ping Google.

If you want to check for packet loss with your cable, you should ping your default gateway, and not an external source.

Comment: True, 2% isn't extreme, but personally it's still more than I'd normally expect from a wired connection...

Comment: if i was to ping my cable source would i do ping then my ip then -n 25 right because i ran that test first giving me 0 packet loss but within games i can start at 0 packet loss then as i get going it spikes to 1 or 2 then eventually 5-20

Comment: @user1147782 whatever your default gateway is when you do `ipconfig` in cmd. If you're having those issues with games, it's probably not your cable connecting to the router, but something else related to your ISP, the game servers, etc. Packet loss is more common than you'd think. What tool are you using to see your packet loss in games?

Comment: i use the in games ping counter it shows me up and down packet loss and im getting most up packet loss while staying at consistent 20 ping i check my default gateway and i was receiving no packet loss after my three tests

Comment: The uplink packet loss seems to be happening in areas that are beyond your control. Packet loss happens more often than you think. If it's not affecting your gameplay, then don't sweat it.

Comment: Your packet loss is not extreme, but is not ideal. I would be using MTR (or winmtr or similar) to effectively combine ping and trace route to get a feel for where the packet loss is occurring.

Comment: the packet loss is affecting my gameplay severely

Comment: What game is it? It’s definitely a problem that is outside of your home network.

Comment: It’s good to here it’s not a problem on my end and fortnite the most ping dependent game out there